# how to filter the huge log file to just contain the useful messages

Tags: linux

I have a huge log files. Every time open the file will cause the system not responsive. I only need to check the log messages that contains certain strings.
Is there an simple way to do it?

Comment: `egrep -Ri string_to_search_for > new_file_containing_what_you_want.txt`. After this finishes you will find everything related to the string you are searching for in that new txt file. You can find more about egrep by running `man egrep` in your terminal.

Answer (score 3):

$cat testlogfile.txt | grep --color=auto TRACE > newlogfile.txt

For example, your huge log file called testlogfile.txt. You only need check the log messages that contains "TRACE".
try this command under linux terminal and go to where the huge log is.
You can open the newlogfile.txt that only contains lines with "TRACE"

If you would like to exclude the lines with "TRACE", try -v option:

$cat testlogfile.txt | grep --color=auto -v TRACE > newlogfile.txt